# ConstraintLayout Prevent Overlap of Top and Bottom Widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create a layout with three groups of widgets. I want one group constrained to the top, one to the bottom, and one to float in the middle of the space between the two groups. The layout will be used in a fragment, so it could become squashed, especially when the keyboard is shown. I am having trouble figuring out how to prevent overlap of the two groups, while keeping the top and bottom constrained to the top and bottom of the layout.

I thought of several ways to do it, but I couldn't figure out how to implement any of the properly.

- Using `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` or `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight` to pull widgets together or spread them apart.
- Using one chain, but having breaks in between the groups. I couldn't figure out how to split the chain part way through to allow the different groups to spread out.
- Specify a minimum height that is dependent upon the contained widgets. (It will be contained in a `ScrollView` so it if the height is constrained it will work)
- Create groups of packed chains where the packed chains are in a spread chain.

Or is there a better way than these to get what I want?

**Note:** I would prefer that the top and bottom groups aren't right against the parent layout, but I couldn't figure out how to get those groups to dynamically distance themselves from the parent layout without also spreading the group apart. I want the top and bottom groups close to the parent layout, but not necessarily right against it. It is better to have them right against the parent layout than close to the middle. Ideally I would be able to use `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` or `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight` for this.

---

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_vertical_margin"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/edit_text_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        android:hint="Edit Text 1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_vertical_margin"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        android:hint="Edit Text 2"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/progress_bar_margin"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clickable_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_button_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_button_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_button_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_button_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_button_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/text_button_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_button_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_button_vertical_margin"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        android:text="Clickable Text View"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Images**

[image: Desired Layout Look] - - - - [image: Overlap Problem]

Here is what I have, and how I want it to look. - - - - - Here is the overlapping problem.

Comment: @JeelVankhede that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

for the textview add a constraint top to bottom of the button ie app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button". IMO always constraint all 4 angles wherever possible; start top end bottom. In that way when your view is 'squashed', it will still adhere to the constraint set

Comment: That is what I originally tried, but that made it so all of the widgets were spread out and not grouped like I want.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here, try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="36dp"
        android:hint="Enter email ID"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="36dp"
        android:hint="Enter password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailId" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInBtn"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Sign in"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/analyticsLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Click me to create a log"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That still has the issue with the `TextView` overlapping the other widgets when the height is small.

Comment: I have uploaded an image it works fine for me. Btw which widgets height you are talking about.

Comment: When I'm talking about the height, I'm talking about the height of the layout as a whole. This is because I'm going to be using this layout as a fragment that can potentially have a small window within the display. When this happens the widgets overlap as shown in the second image.

Comment: May I see the layout where you including this layout code. And in TextView add one more line 'app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/signInBtn" ' then it will fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) together with `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` to solve your problem.

**Consider this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text_2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="Edit Text 2"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text_1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="Edit Text 1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/edit_text_2"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clickable_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Clickable Text View"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />
```

- Every view height is equal to `10%` of the screen height, that's because of the `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"` attribute. This will solve the overlapping problem for you because you will be able to tell your view what height to be relative to the screen size.
- I was using guidelines as well with the `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35"` attribute to tell the guideline were to be on the screen, by doing that I can constrain different views to it and you won't have to stick your views to the top of bottom of the screen as you mentioned (*I would prefer that the top and bottom groups aren't right against the parent layout*)

**Your layout will look like this:(this is preview image for better understanding guidelines)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for who has same problem. use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` with `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` to attach the view to botom. if use `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"`the view will attach to top.

```
<TextView

  ...

  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"/>
```